# CSV not returning rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

been stuck on this all morning. I've been following this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/cd2c9da1388565a6fb9ce5fba95168db#prices.csv)

I've been trying to get this to work in React but sadly no luck. I was able to read the csv in before and console log the data so I know it's finding the right file. What am I missing here?

```
class Linegraph extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

    var margin = { left: 50, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 50 };

    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var max = 0;

    var xNudge = 50;
    var yNudge = 20;

    var minDate = new Date();
    var maxDate = new Date();

    d3.csv("MOCK_DATA.csv")
      .row(function(d) {
        return {
          month: parseDate(d.month),
          price: Number(d.price.trim().slice(1))
        };
      })
      .get(function(error, rows) {
        max = d3.max(rows, function(d) {
          return d.price;
        });
        minDate = d3.min(rows, function(d) {
          return d.month;
        });
        maxDate = d3.max(rows, function(d) {
          return d.month;
        });
    .................
```

Comment: What version of D3?

Comment: d3 v4 is what I'm using

Comment: Ok, just checking, because that `d3.csv` pattern wouldn't work with v5.

Comment: Oh I am using V5, how do I change it to work with version 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(note: this question is not a duplicate of the existing Q/A about the new d3.fetch module because it uses a row function, not covered on those Q/A)*

Since you are using D3 v5, you have to change the XmlHttpRequest pattern of v4 to the new Promises pattern of v5 (see the [documentation here](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#dsv)).

So, your code should be:

```
d3.csv("MOCK_DATA.csv", function(d) {
        return {
            month: parseDate(d.month),
            price: Number(d.price.trim().slice(1))
        };
    })
    .then(function(rows) {
    //etc...
    });
```

Pay attention to the fact that the row function goes inside the `d3.csv` function, as the second argument.